# Issue with ESLint in Nuxt

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, eslint

I'm learning Nuxt. I've set up a project, with ESLint included. Here's my `index.vue`:

```
<template>
    <h1 class=reddo>Hello, world</h1>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    head() {
      // Set Meta Tags for this Page
    }
    // ...
  }
</script>

<style>
  .reddo {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
```

When I run this I get this:

[image]

(It doesn't *say* this is from ESLint, but I assume it is). The first error complains about the indentation before the `<h1>`. Do I need to do something to make it understand `.vue` files so it validates only the `<script>` part or something?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The default configuration must lint the entire `.vue` file, as it understands them. There are some [limitations to the parser as well which may be triggering your linter](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-eslint-parser#%EF%B8%8F-known-limitations)

Comment: Thanks. What's odd is I've followed the Nuxt intro video exactly, so it's odd that they didn't get, or at least didn't warn about, this problem. So ESLinting `.vue` files isn't a thing?

Comment: Yes, it is a thing. When you follow that guide, it will create a project that extends a config from `@nuxt/eslint-config` which [looks something like this file](https://github.com/nuxt/eslint-config/blob/master/packages/eslint-config/index.js). You can change or disable this configuration by editing your `.eslintrc.js` file in your project folder

Comment: Right, but I don't know what to change it *to*, or why I'd disable which part of it. This is the information I'm lacking. Feel free to post an answer and I'll gladly give you the rep if you're inclined to do so. Thanks so far.

Comment: ESlint may actually help you. Why not generating a configuration that may help you in your daily work? Create a fresh new Nuxt project and copy pasta the content from it to yours. It can help you debug some things sometimes, to spot errors before runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Since you followed the Nuxt intro video, you likely have a `.eslintrc.js` file in your project folder that extends a config from `@nuxt/eslint-config` that adds this parser and some default rules ([source code](https://github.com/nuxt/eslint-config/blob/master/packages/eslint-config/index.js)).

The default configuration is linting the entire `.vue` file, as the Vue parser understands them. There are [some limitations to the parser](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-eslint-parser#%EF%B8%8F-known-limitations) as well which may be triggering your linter if there were any changes not from the Nuxt config.

You can change or disable this configuration by editing your `.eslintrc.js` file; however, there are many advantages to statically analyzing your code using a linter. So consider finding or making a config that has few stylistic rules (or ones that you like) so you can still catch possible errors, [including ones specific to Vue](https://eslint.vuejs.org/).

If you want to revert to a working `.eslintrc.js` file, try copying the changes from a new create-nuxt-app.

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint'
  },
  extends: [
    '@nuxtjs',
    'plugin:nuxt/recommended'
  ],
  plugins: [
  ],
  // add your custom rules here
  rules: {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The thing is, I'm surprised the Nuxt video didn't mention this. You follow their exact steps, then run the code, and are met with ESLint errors because, as you say, it's linting the entire file, when it should actually just lint the parts in the `<script>` tag. This seems a daft omission and confusing for noobs. I've no idea how to configure the `.eslintrc.js` to cater for `.vue` files but I will do some digging. It's the sort of thing I'd have thought people had done many times already.

Comment: It *should* lint the entire file, not just the script tag. Why are you wanting to not lint it all?

Comment: I think we're getting crossed wires. I do want to lint. But currently it's erroneously reporting (as per my original post) that there's incorrect indentation, in the HTML part of the `.vue` file. Since the `h1` is a child of `template`, it should of course be indented. I assumed from this it was somehow thinking the entire file was JavaScript, and linting it incorrectly.

Comment: Okay, I see. Can you post your ESLint config? I added a working configuration that's the default solution from create-nuxt-app if you want to try it as well.

Comment: My `eslintrc.js` is identical to the one you posted. Like yours, it arrived app `create-next-app`. Nonetheless, I get the errors shown when I run the project.